# Building objects from multiple async server queries

Tags: java, design, asynchronous-programming

I'm building a system that uses objects that are built using multiple Async queries to a remote server (Firebase) and queries to a local DB.

How should I design a module to generate these objects?

I was thinking of using a [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) but almost all of these variables will be received individually from separate DB queries and not specified in a .build() call.

**Example of object:**

```
public class ContactUserObject {

//The userID to identify the user in the system (gotten from network call)
private final String contactUserID;
//The contact's phone number; (found locally)
private final String contactPhoneNumber;
//The public display name; (gotten from Firebase)
private final String contactPublicDisplayName;
//Name of contact in phone; (found locally)
private final String contactLocalDisplayName;
//Public contact profile picture
private final Bitmap contactCustomProfilePicture;
}
```

reference for more detail:
http://arvindthirumurthy.com/creational-patterns-for-user-object-creation/

Answer (score 1):

I would use a repository with an async Get method.

This separates out the data and build methods from your object and gives you a sensible place to synchronise all the async calls.

Also, it incorporates the concept of 'loading' rather than creating an empty object